# Temporary domains when when moving applications to new server

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdomain, iis

I'm currently in the process of moving 20 .Net applications from a dedicated Windows 2008 server to a new 2016 server. How can I ensure the sites are working correctly on a temp domain before I redirect the live domains to the new server?

Lets say my server has been set up with the following domain:

`http://2016Server.example.com`

On my 2008 server I have the following sites:

`https://courses.example.com`

`https://students.example.com`

I realise I could just set up the following temp domains until im happy to redirect one by one.

`https://courses-temp.example.com`

`https://students-temp.example.com`

Is there a better way of doing this? Is it possible to set up each site in IIS and then add bindings for each site like so?

`http://2016Server.example.com/courses`

`http://2016Server.example.com/students`

If so, is there anything to look out for when doing it this way?